# Game Institute Math Courses

Tags: mathematics, physics, trigonometry

I'm 21 years old and I suck at math, I mean really bad. I don't have the necessary logic to apply it towards programming. I would like to learn the math and logic of applying it. I found Game Institute (http://www.gameinstitute.com) awhile back and heard a lot of praise about them. Are there Math courses any good?

Thank you.

**Edit:** My high school was terrible and did not prepare me for any math. I am fairly decent at programming, I just don't have the logic to apply any mathematics to programming, as an example I don't understand the algorithm of finding the size of a user's screen.

Yes I have heard of KhanAcademy (http://www.khanacademy.org/) and I have completed a lot of maths on his website but I still don't have the logic to apply any of it to programming.

Comment: Have you looked at [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/)? It's supposed to be awesome and it's free.

Comment: What do you mean by "math"? If you mean you don't understand those cryptic formulas everywhere, don't sweat about it, that's absolutely not necessary. You don't need to understand cryptic formulas, you just need to be able the concept behind the algorithms. And math is not needed for that. That formulas are more math for maths sake.

Answer (score 4):

If you suck at maths you don't want to be starting at the game development level because game maths generally uses some advanced concepts, e.g. matrices and some calculus. Other things like vectors, trigonometry (or anything to do with angles) aren't so complex but they aren't beginner-level either.

#### Try [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/).

Learn the basics first, then worry about learning stuff specific to game development.

Their courses cover most of the American high school curriculum, and there is a significant amount of maths education available on the site. They're also free-as-in-Wikipedia because the guy who runs the site can afford to do that.

Once you've learned the basics you can also learn stuff specific to game development from Khan Academy, because they teach [Linear Algebra](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra) and [Geometry](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry) and other game development topics too.

So: **No. Don't use Game Institute.** First because you suck at maths, second because even if you didn't you can learn the maths for free.

Comment: +1 First to suggest Khan academy. You don't need pictures to get my vote!

Answer (score 2):

I have access to Game Institute and I do think all of the courses I've done are really good, including the math course. *However*, if you really want to start from the very basics, I would recommend that you watch the videos from **[Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/)** instead. Some points of interest:

- It's completely *free*!
- Sal who founded the site, is a great teacher, and his videos are both informative and fun.
- The videos start from the *very* basics such as [basic addition](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/addition-subtraction/v/basic-addition) all the way up to [calculus](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/v/calculus--derivatives-1--new-hd-version) and [differential equations](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/v/what-is-a-differential-equation). So you can jump in no matter what level you are.
- There are exercises for you to practice what you learn, and a road map that tells you what you should study next (check image below).
- As a bonus, it also covers *many* other subjects besides maths if you're interested.

[image]

After you have at least the high school basics down, the Game Institute course will probably make a lot more sense that it would right now. It will probably still be useful because it's very game oriented, dealing with subjects such as vectors, matrix and quaternions, in the context of game development. Still, the Khan Academy will probably be enough since it's quite complete, and actually covers a lot more than the Game Institute course.

Comment: I have the basic high school principles down from KhanAcademy and other sources that the high school I graduated from never cared to teach me *added edit in post* but I don't know or have the logic to apply those maths to programming. If I figured this step out then I would be good to go.

Comment: @W3Geek If you don't understand how to apply maths to programming you probably don't understand the maths that well.

Comment: I can easily apply converting things back and forth in programming but code formulas like x = radius * cos(angle); or i = 1000 * (maxHours / 2); I don't understand how the developers get these code formulas. Is it through trial and error or what.

Comment: @W3Geek No, it's not trial and error, they understand perfectly well what they're writing. They're applying some arithmetic to get a particular result. Which is why I said, and it turns out I'm right: If you don't understand how to apply this, it's because you don't understand the maths. Your issue isn't that you need to learn programming, or how to apply maths to programming - you need to learn maths. If your high school was terrible... Khan Academy isn't your high school and _isn't_ terrible. Go and start learning.

Answer (score 0):

Math is hard enough to learn in 4 years with a teacher guiding you.  I honestly don't see how you can learn it on your own by following web tutorials.  My suggestion is enroll in math course at college or university.

Comment: Consider that web tutorials do have a teacher guiding you - the writer. Also high school maths is not only extremely slow paced, boring and often low quality (none of which are problems at Khan Academy), [it isn't really mathematics at all](http://www.maa.org/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf). This spoken by someone who _did_ enroll in maths courses in University, _does_ learn maths through other sources as well _and_ applies that math programmatically. Maths courses are valuable, but they aren't the only way to learn.